# how to give raw_input to subprocess

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to convert a shell script into python.

**Shell command:**

```
BR_EX=br-ex
ovs-vsctl add-br $BR_EX.
```

**In python:**

```
BR_EX = raw_input()   #User will input br-ex
b = subprocess.Popen("ovs-vsctl add-br $BR_EX", shell=True, stdin=None, stderr=None, executable="/bin/bash")
```

I want to achieve something like this. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string formatting routines to do so:

```
b = subprocess.Popen("ovs-vsctl add-br '{}'".format(BR_EX), ...)
```

or:

```
b = subprocess.Popen("ovs-vsctl add-br '%s'" % (BR_EX, ), ...)
```

You may not to invoke subshell, than it will be even easier:

```
b = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/ovs-vsctl', 'add-br', BR_EX], 
                     stdin=None, stderr=None)
```